# How to make F5 shortcut for send/receive in Outlook instead of F9

Tags: outlook

I am using outlook 2010.

Is there a way to make F5 key a shorcut for "send/receive" in outlook 2010?

Thank you

Comment: What you mean? Little confusing

Comment: I want to make that when I press F5 in outlook 2010 , this will activate the "send/receive" feature. Like a refresh to the mail

Comment: not possible to override the shortcuts in outlook.